# Access Two tables in one program using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

i have two table and i wants to add the columns of those two tables.if the First column(File_Name)of TrueResult table equal to the First column(F_Name) of MyResult table then add 2nd and 3rd columns of both table
**TrueResult**

```
File_Name    Pos_Score    Neg_Score     

p46084445    3.25         2.5
p46084231    2.8          1.5    
p46084412    1.8          2.9
```

**MyResult**

```
F_Name       P_Score      N_Score     

p46084231    2.25         1.5
p46084412    3.8          2.5    
p46084445    2.8          3.9
```

**Example**
since the first row of TrueResult table is equal the 3rd row of MyResult table so we add the result.

```
Pos_Score=2.8+3.25
Neg_Score=3.9 +2.5
```

i writes the following code to solve this problem.
**Code**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConString = "server=localhost;" +
           "database=WordNet;" + "password=zia;" +
           "User Id=root;";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from TrueResult,MyResult where TrueResult.File_Name=MyResult.F_Name;", con);
        con.Close();
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            textBox3.Text = r["Pos_Score.TrueResult"].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = r["Neg_Score.TrueResult"].ToString();
            textBox1.Text = r["P_Score.MyResult"].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = r["N_Score.MyResult"].ToString();
            pos = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            neg = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            post = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            negt = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            pos1 = pos + post;
            neg1 = neg + negt;
            MessageBox.Show("pos=" + pos1.ToString() + "neg" + neg1.ToString());
            r.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

and this program gives the following error.
**Error**
Unknown column 'MyResult.F_Name' in 'where clause'
  Any one helpe me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your query, you are using the all character which is `*`, therefore you are not using `COLUMN ALIAS`. You will have the following results:

```
File_Name   Pos_Score   Neg_Score   F_Name      P_Score N_Score
p46084445   3.25        2.5         p46084445   2.8     3.9
```

You should change your code from:

```
textBox3.Text = r["Pos_Score.TrueResult"].ToString();
textBox2.Text = r["Neg_Score.TrueResult"].ToString();
textBox1.Text = r["P_Score.MyResult"].ToString();
textBox4.Text = r["N_Score.MyResult"].ToString();
```

to:

```
textBox3.Text = r["Pos_Score"].ToString();
textBox2.Text = r["Neg_Score"].ToString();
textBox1.Text = r["P_Score"].ToString();
textBox4.Text = r["N_Score"].ToString();
```

or you can just go with this query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(TR.Pos_Score + MR.P_Score, 0) AS PositiveScore
    , IFNULL(TR.Neg_Score + MR.N_Score, 0) AS NegativeScore
    FROM TrueResult TR
    INNER JOIN MyResult MR ON MR.F_Name = TR.File_Name;
```

and use the following code:

```
pos1 = Convert.ToDouble(r["PositiveScore"].ToString());
neg1 = Convert.ToDouble(r["NegativeScore"].ToString());
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly :) I guess they just have to cater for NULLS also (if the scores are nullable columns). I don't know the MySQL syntax for this though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Mr Moose, I just assume that there are no `NULL` values for this. Anyway, editing my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do this all in one query;

```
SELECT TrueResult.File_Name, Pos_Score + P_Score As Pos_Score, Neg_Score + N_Score AS Neg_Score 
FROM TrueResult 
INNER JOIN MyResult ON TrueResult.File_Name = MyResult.F_Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you do that on the query itself? Seems easier to me.
Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT File_Name SUM(Pos_Score) SUM(Neg_Score)
FROM TrueResult, MyResult where TrueResult.FileName=MyResult.FileName
GROUP BY TrueResult.File_Name
```

Just a sketch, that isn't entirely correct.
Any special reason you want to do this outside mysql?